# CursorTreeAdapter and Expandable ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

i have implemented a CursorTreeAdapter, and im using it to fetch data from a sqlite Database which contains information about days. Now i want those days to be grouped as months. for that i implemented a Cursor returning a list of Months + Years, and a child cursor that retrieves the days that are supposed to be in that group.

My group cursor seems to be running just fine, i get the mm.YYYY as a group header, at least on some older devices, tested it on a newer one and there it crashes for no obvious reasons. As it doesn't contain any code from my project, im not really sure about how to fix this.

```
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:436)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:191)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:422)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2180)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1447)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2438)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
12-12 12:54:38.671: E/AndroidRuntime(11329):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyway on an older device the header appears as intended. but throws a similar stacktrace when clicking the header. So my guess is that the newer phones tried to expand the Group for me without having to actually click it.

```
01-03 21:48:06.656: E/CursorWindow(16844): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 2
01-03 21:48:06.656: W/dalvikvm(16844): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:412)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:108)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:437)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:192)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:421)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:745)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1088)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2744)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3669)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1769)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1135)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1753)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2227)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1886)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-03 21:48:06.664: E/AndroidRuntime(16844):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have Checked other similar problems but there was at least one point at which the Stacktrace refereed to the actual workspace. But in this case i have no idea what i going on. All i can tell is that the getChildrenCursor of the CursorTreeAdapter has not been called at the point the app crashes because i added a println to the methods body.

And this is how i setup the group cursor, im not calling movetoFirst as thats supposed to managed by the CursorTreeAdapter and appears to work since it displays on header with proper content.

```
public Cursor getGroupCursor(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT STRFTIME('%m', " + INTAKE_KEY_DATE
                + ") as month, STRFTIME('%Y', " + INTAKE_KEY_DATE + ") as year " +
                "FROM " + TABLENAME_INTAKE;

        return db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
    }
```

If you need any additional code, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it,

The documentation states that every table has to have a column named _id, which mine doesnt. at least for now :)